# How to implement IEnumerable using a return call to IEnumerator? C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I'm getting a frustrating error in my code which does not allow me to implement IEnumerable for a class I have created.  Let me post the code, as it always makes more sense and it is very short here...

```
[Serializable]
internal class GroupNode : IGroupNode, IEnumerable<ISceneNode>
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    const int NumberOfChildren = 8;
    #region Member variables
    private IList<ISceneNode> children = new List<ISceneNode>(NumberOfChildren);
    #endregion

    public IEnumerator<ISceneNode> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return children.GetEnumerator(); //***
    }
...
}
```

And the interface:

```
 public interface IGroupNode : ISceneNode, IEnumerable<ISceneNode>
{
    void AddChild(ISceneNode child);
}
```

And finally, the error message (it is actually pretty descriptive):

```
Error   1   'Project.SceneGraphCore.GroupNode' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'Project.SceneGraphCore.GroupNode.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.    C:\Users\Ian\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ISceneGraph\SceneGraph\GroupNode.cs  11  20  SceneGraph
```

Just what have I done wrong here?  All I did was take my collection class, which is based off of a list, and return the List's GetEnumerator method.  But then, in the error message, it is saying I have not implemented IEnumerable...  I thought that returning GetEnumerator would be sufficient, but I cannot tell in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable` (the non-generic version).  Any time you implement the generic method you also need to provide a non-generic counterpart.

If you simply right click the interface in Visual Studio it will automatically stub out the functions for you, but you can manually add it if you prefer.

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return children.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Just add that to the class *in addition to the existing methods*.